# Renaming Master of Divinity

Tags: masters, united-states, degree

I no longer feel comfortable with my master's degree (Master of Divinity). Especially for theologists, the title of education should not be racially problematic (calling myself a master might make others feel like slaves). I don't need the MDiv for my job, so I am reaching out for having my degree invalidated.

Now, if I want to have the term "Master of Divinity" changed to a more welcoming title, where would I start? Is there a committee responsible for these titles? Let's assume this applies to the US first, before going global.

Comment: **Close voters**: The question is clearly answerable, even if you think it's wrongheaded.

Comment: Please note, the question is about **how to get an academic degree renamed.** For discussion on whether this particular renaming is necessary (or other topics), please use the [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113542/discussion-on-question-by-dont-wanna-mdiv-renaming-master-of-divinity).

Comment: You *cannot* change the name of your degree.  Even if you can get the University to change the designation, it would apply to *future* graduates of the degree.  Imagine the confusion with the recognition of the degree if some arranged to retroactively have a different designation.. .

Comment: You can be a Bachelor, even if you're married.

Answer (score 6):

No, generally speaking, degrees cannot and won't be renamed after you've received them. While it would be fine to not use the title in day-to-day life (e.g. an email signature), most people would consider it inappropriate to leave it off a resume or CV. Degrees are only revoked when you did something fraudulent to obtain it.

You also cannot rename it (in formal contexts) as the comments suggest, e.g. to "MSc in Theology." You shouldn't insert things like "of Science" or "of Arts" where they don't belong in any context, though.

As far as your specific objection, I don't think it's anything you have to worry about, and I say that as someone pretty far to the left.

If you truly did want to remove "master" from all degrees, you would have to talk to 1) your university and 2) the accrediting body for theological degrees. I cannot imagine you would be very successful.

Comment: ‘’You also cannot rename it as the comments suggest (e.g. to "MSc in Theology") although that wouldn't seem to fix your problem anyway.‘’ Surely not on a CV, but I do not see any problem in doing that in everyday's life, if the concern is not making people feeling ‘‘inferior’’.

Comment: @neutroshock Fair enough, that's what I meant to imply. I would say though that claiming to have a "Masters of Science in Theology" when you have a "Master of Divinity" is stretching too far, and doesn't fix the OP's objections

Comment: @Azor Ahai, sure, changing the title into Master in ‘something else’ would not address the problem, as the issue is with the master word.

Comment: @neutroshock Yeah, that's what I said.

Comment: It’s clear. In my first comments I thought the problem was with ‘divinity’.

Comment: 'Degrees are only revoked when you did something fraudulent'  At the University of Cambridge, it's possible to resign one's membership of the university (Cambridge University Ordinances chapter II), the consequences of which include cancellation of all degrees one has been awarded by the university (Cambridge University statute B I 2).  Maybe OP's alma mater has a similar procedure.  But I urge OP to think twice before going ahead: on searching Google, Google Scholar, and Google Books, I can't find any trace that anyone thinks the use of "master" in "master's degree" is reminiscent of slavery.

Comment: @DanielHatton Interesting, I have never heard of such a procedure at a secular university in the states.

Comment: @DanielHatton: Clearly, avoiding those terms is just starting. You'll not find many references yet. Most active IMHO is the IT sector, like https://summit.sfu.ca/item/20478 I also see (some will say "unnecessary") clarifications for those terms in https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/9138718 I agree, it is mostly applied to master/slave pairs until now. Then I found https://www.bbc.com/news/technology-53050955 and I was affirmed this does not affect a master/slave pair. The slave is implicit.

Comment: @Don'twannaMDiv The usage of "master" in GitHub is much closer to the master/slave sense than "master of science" or "master of nursing" or "master of ceremonies." If the divinity degree was "master of the flock" then I think your objection would make more sense. "Master" certainly doesn't imply there is a slave.

Comment: Hardware frequently have a master/slave terminology because it literally is a master and a slave relationship. It isn't offensive because it describes what it actually **is**; one piece of hardware/software directly controlling another. The ethical concern is applicable to **human** interaction. You being a "Master" of an academic subject probably won't invoke thoughts of slavery.

Comment: It's safe to say the word in general is started to be looked at unfavorably and is being avoided when possible.  Even words like "blacklist" are being relooked at, even though it has utterly nothing to do with race. Here's an article that came out recently: https://www.cnn.com/2020/07/06/us/racism-words-phrases-slavery-trnd/index.html .  Master in the sense of academics really isn't that far off from master in "The Masters Tournament".

Comment: @eps I don't want to get too far into the weeds here, but "blacklist" is looked down on because it uses "black" to mean bad, not because of the etymology - that's not the claim. I think it's pretty distinct from "the Masters," and the article even goes into the racist history of golf and that tournament.

Answer (score 4):

You should keep in mind that the “master/slave” dynamic is not inherently racist, particularly as it is applied to a graduate degree. You can definitely view the word “master” as racist if you try to and spin it to fit that type of narrative if you feel like, but most seeing that you have a “masters” degree, will not presume that you’re a racist or that you are racially insensitive for achieving a masters degree.

Nevertheless, you’d need to speak with the institution that awarded you the degree and they would, I imagine, have to put out a statement of some kind to apply it to all degrees awarded in the past and future. While I understand you feel a certain way, you should bare in mind that it’s really just not a big deal for an overwhelming majority of people. If you do want to appease a small margin of people though, I wish you luck on your journey.

Comment: FYI you "bear in mind"

Comment: "really just not a big deal for an overwhelming majority of people" - if you have a scientific study on that, I'd greatly appreciate reading it

Comment: Shouldn't the person asking that everyone's degree be renamed be providing the "scientific study"?

Comment: @RaghuParthasarathy: as I commented elsewhere: I'll provide reasoning, i.e. potentially including a study.

Comment: No need for a scientific demonstration. I have never seen such a complaint before, so I can infer beyond any reasonable doubt that it is not ‘a big deal for an overwhelming majority of people’. If anything, you should prove that this is a concern for the other people, especially for those who are going to have their title changed. And the original Latin word for Master (Magister) has no racial implications.

Comment: @neutroshock: Inference, well ... How many black, poor, uneducated people do you have contact to? Latin? You know about slavery in Roman Republic? Why do you say the Latin word is without racial implications?

Comment: Magister, Magistri (masc.) / Magistra, magistrae (fem.): noun, 2nd declension. Teacher, tutor, master, expert, chief. Note ‘expert’ among them. In fact, your title states that you’re expert in your field. Without any slavery implications.

Comment: The fact that Romans practiced slavery does not mean that a Latin word is racist or slavery-related. In Spain, France, Italy and countries with Latin languages in general, the equivalent of magister is simply used as teacher.

Comment: I downvoted this because it entertains the idea of renaming a degree who's intent is to declare "mastery", i.e. complete understanding, of a field. Moreover it suggests, wrongfully I believe, that an accredited institution could possibly make an exception for naming in order to promote virtue. The principle is absurd at it's face and OP needs consider the etymology of the word in the context of the name of the degree.

Comment: It’s not a great answer, but it’s also not a great question, so I accept the downvote.

Comment: @neutroshock that's true but it's also irrelevant as many words are coming out of fire even though their roots have nothing to do with race or slavery. Blacklist, for example.  Or 'The Masters Tournament" : https://www.cnn.com/2020/07/06/us/racism-words-phrases-slavery-trnd/index.html

Comment: @Don'twannaMDiv slavery in roman times had nothing to do with race.  The concept of race really didn't even exist in the modern context.

Comment: @CL40 as my link shows, people (including scholars of race and racism) clearly disagree with you. etymology is not the only concern.

Comment: *a correction about my Latin comment, since I can no longer edit: 2nd declension only refer to the masculine noun (magister, magistri), the feminine one (magistra, magistrae) obviously obeys to another declension (1st). That was quite gross from my side.

Comment: @eps CNN is a very poor source on an academic forum. For what it's worth I read your article and they use "...but the connotation" to justify what amounts to an opinion does not lend credence to your argument when https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/master clearly shows the first definition in the list is the exact etymology of the term "master" in this regard. The level of mental gymnastics required to relate a Master's Degree to some specter of racism is quite incredible. As for the scholars you suppose - when you need to find racism to make tenure you tend to see it everywhere.